# How to parse an Integer for SimpleDateFormat()

Tags: android, kotlin, simpledateformat

I want to show the Integer "zeitMinuten" and "zeitStunden" in my TextView with the "mm" and "HH" Format.

Now my TextView is just "00". When I just do "actualMinutes.text = zeitMinuten.toString()" will look like "0", "1" ... "10" but I want "00", "01".

I hope you understand my problem.

```
fun timers() {

        var timer = object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                zeitMinuten += 1
                ausgabeZahl(zeitMinuten,zeitStunden)

                actualMinutes.text = SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(zeitMinuten)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                zeitStunden += 1
                ausgabeZahl(zeitMinuten,zeitStunden)

                actualHours.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(zeitStunden)

                zeitMinuten = 0

                timers()
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Comment: What about formatting the value with `String.format("%02d", SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(zeitMinuten));`? Or better, what about using `java.time`?

Comment: I used your idea but now the app crashes everytime ^^ "java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String" and I dont know how to use java.time but I can try look for examples

Comment: Ok it works with "... = String.format("%02d",zeitMinuten)" thank you

Comment: Sorry, was just a guess, of course the argument for a `%d` in `String.format` must be numeric.

Comment: always use english in function and variable names, this is a generally accepted world practice

Comment: Thanks, I will do that in future projects